# Cheapest way to communicate with a Fez Panda II (or Arduino board)?

Tags: arduino, communication, ethernet

I have an application where I will have 30 Fez Panda II boards connected together. They will be spread out over an area of about 100' x 150'.

I prefer TCP/IP communciation, but adding a FEZ Connect Shield adds the cost of $35/each and I was hoping to have something less expensive.

I would gladly even utilize the built in USB cable, if only a way to connect them all to a computer over that long distance.

Answer (score 1):

Have the serial out of one go to the serial in of the next, create a big loop.  Make your own simple packet structure and protocol.  If a board gets a packet that is not addressed to it it just passes it on.  Cheaper than usb or ethernet cable, no shields, very little software required.  if you do have long stretches then you might consider adding a differential pair, like an rs422 transceiver (422? 485? which is it?)

Comment: if this is one way communication, from a host or controller of some sort and the fex/arduino's are just slaves then you only need one wire fed to all boards if you can handle the fan out. same kind of protocol, if the board doesnt recognize its address in the packet it discards it.

Comment: then the round robin/token ring thing will work

Comment: You are suggesting something different than a bus, like RS485? This needs to be a correct circle and it can't be broken, right?

Comment: yes that is what I am suggesting.  a full circle.   there are other simple interfaces that will work as well.  Does this need to be a master slave situation or everyone can talk to everyone?

Comment: It will be a master-slave situation. I was considering i2c but I don't know if it will go the distances I need (maybe 500' total bus length)

Comment: right, you could try a dallas one wire type thing, with the actual dallas semi parts they would go 1000 feet so they said.  its the same as i2c or spi, shared wires with a pull up going a long way.

Comment: maybe wireless if you can find a transceiver that is complete (antenna) for well under the price of the ethernet option I think this needs an antenna and I dont see the range listed http://www.sparkfun.com/products/9582

Comment: http://www.sparkfun.com/products/10665 a microcontroller and wireless for $20 it may only go 50' so that may not work for your 150'

Comment: instead of a circle using the serial ports where it has to be a closed circle, you could have two interfaces per chip, i2c, serial, spi, homebrew, etc. and they can be configured in a line instead of a closed circle, if a message comes in on interface A and it is not for me then I echo it to B if it comes in on B and not mine I echo on A.  If it comes in on B and is for me I reply on B if comes in on A and for me I reply on A.  Then you only have to worry about point to point, dont need a pull up for a wired or signal, etc.  Just thinking out loud, hope it helps

Comment: ahh, yes, the lpc2387 has four uarts, you could use two of those to create either a unidirectional ring, bidirectional ring or linear configuration.  And go a fair number of feet with rs232 point to point without needing to go differential.  hmm, did they expose more than one uart on the fez panda board?  The $20 stm32f4 discovery has at least two exposed to the external pins.

Answer (score 1):

Using RS485 is the way to go. You can then put MODBUS or some other similar protocol on top of it. You will find valuable information here: http://www.modbus.org/specs.php

Comment: We actually did use RS485 for the first pass, I was wondering if there was a better option, but I guess this was the way to go. Thanks.

Comment: Then you can opt for CAN networking (with RS485 still beeing the cheapest solution). Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264889/does-the-net-micro-framework-support-the-can-bus